# DataGridComboBoxColumn bound to Model Property Does not Update

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to bind a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to a property in the model which is another model where i face either one of two problems:

- The value of the Property is not shown when the DataGridComboBoxColumn is shown initally, or
- The value is shown, but the Combobox does not update the Property correctly

Form after app is started (this is an example app to demonstrate the problem, the real app only has one Vat-Column)

[image]

VatCombo1 does not show the value of the Vat property

VatCombo2 does not show the value of the Vat property

VatCombo3 shows the value of the Vat property correctly

Form after value of VatCombo1 has been changed to 19 --> VatId and VatRate are shown correctly

[image]

Form after the value VatCombo3 has been changed to 19 --> VatRate is not updated

[image]

How can I get to the ´DataGridComboBoxColumn´ to work? I.e. show the initial value stored in the model property, and change the value when another item is selected from the `Combobox` to the right Id **AND** Rate?

Idealley VatCombo1 approach to show the value on inital load?

Property in the model

```
    private VatModel vat;

    public VatModel Vat
    {
        get { return vat; }
        set
        {
            vat = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Vat)));
        }
    }
```

Viewmodel

```
    public ViewModel()
    {
        VatList.Add(new VatModel(1, 0.00));
        VatList.Add(new VatModel(2, 7.00));
        VatList.Add(new VatModel(3, 19.00));

        VatModel receiptItemVat = new VatModel(2, 7.00);
        ReceiptItemModel receiptItem = new ReceiptItemModel(1, receiptItemVat);

        ReceiptModel receipt = new ReceiptModel();
        receipt.Id = 10;
        receipt.Items.Add(receiptItem);

        Receipt = receipt;      
    }
```

Xalm

```
<Window x:Class="datagridcombo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:datagridcombo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"        
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding  VatList}" x:Key="VatListRes"/>
    </Window.Resources>



    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Content="{Binding Receipt.Id}"/>

        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Receipt.Items}" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ReceiptItemId" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="80"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="VatId" Binding="{Binding Vat.Id}" Width="80"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="VatRate" Binding="{Binding Vat.Rate}" Width="80"/>

                <!-- Initial value not shown, Property update works -->
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="VatCombo1"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource VatListRes}}"
                                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Vat, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"}"
                                        DisplayMemberPath="Rate"
                                        />

                <!-- Initial value not shown, Property update when Enter is hit -->
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="VatCombo2"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource VatListRes}}"
                                        SelectedValuePath="Id"
                                        DisplayMemberPath="Rate"
                                        />

                <!-- Initial value not shown, Property not updated -->
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="VatCombo3"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource VatListRes}}"
                                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Vat.Id, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        SelectedValuePath="Id"
                                        DisplayMemberPath="Rate"
                                        />


            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

When linking objects always make sure you are using the same reference. In your case you are linking the selected item to the items source of the `ComboBox`, but the initial value's instance is not part of the `ComboBox.ItemsSource`. So the `ComboBox` doesn't select anything. `ComboBox` or `ItemsControl` in general checks for reference equality too in order to know which item to select when `SelectedItem` is set.

To fix this, initialize the selected value with an instance of the `ItemsSource`:

```
public ViewModel()
{
  VatList.Add(new VatModel(1, 0.00));

  var initialSelectedItem = new VatModel(2, 7.00);
  VatList.Add(initialSelectedItem);

  VatList.Add(new VatModel(3, 19.00));

  VatModel receiptItemVat = initialSelectedItem;
  ReceiptItemModel receiptItem = new ReceiptItemModel(1, receiptItemVat);

  ReceiptModel receipt = new ReceiptModel();
  receipt.Id = 10;
  receipt.Items.Add(receiptItem);

  Receipt = receipt;      
}
```

Comment: Agreed with @BionicCode, it took time and efforts to generate all the classes and implement code for myself to actually replicate the question.

Comment: Hi BionicCode. Your advice was quite good, in the sense that if the question author follows it, their questions will be better in the future. However, there were two problems: (a) it was a bit hostile, and thus the OP might have been discouraged from replying to you, (b) it is not of interest to other readers. Commentary about the question and how it is posed is best added separately as comments under the question, which means that answer material can then focus on answers.